# iOS VoiceOver Override Magic Tap in CallKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, voiceover, callkit

I am using CallKit to make a call.

In the InCall ViewController I have MagicTap gesture overridden:

```
- (BOOL)accessibilityPerformMagicTap
{
    // ...
    return YES;
}
```

However when I use the MagicTap guesture, it ignores the overridden method. Instead it ends the call.

How can I change this behavior to my custom action?

Comment: Maybe is there something special with Callkit because I think the Magic Tap is a default gesture that automatically starts or ends the call. However, its method can be overriden hassle-free in a 'simple' view controller (I never worked with CallKit, sorry).

Comment: Ask directly the authors of this tutorial : https://www.raywenderlich.com/1276414-callkit-tutorial-for-ios. They should be very helpful.